# Sending serial data to FPGA design on ZedBoard

Tags: python, serial-port, fpga, uart, vivado

I've created a receiver design for a UART. Testing with stimuli on the testbench does indeed show correct functionality. What I am now to try is to test it on real hardware, but I am not sure how to be able to send data serially from the PC to the FPGA with a specific baud rate.

[Desired output `data_out_sim` (shown as ASCII) for binary input `data_in_sim`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moHqX.png)

People have been mentioning using **pySerial** but I am not sure how to make the *connection* between code and hardware design.

Comment: *"I am not sure how to be able to send data serially from the PC ..."* -- Exactly what interface does your project present to the PC? A UART (with TTL signals or RS-232)? Or the FPGA side?  *"... but I am not sure how to make the connection between code and hardware design."* -- That's because you have not clearly established what interface of the PC you will use for this *"connection"*.  The *"FPGA design on ZedBoard"* part of your title is irrelevant to the actual problem.  You neglect to clearly define the PC and its OS.

Comment: *"Desired output `data_out_sim` ... for binary input `data_in_sim`"* -- Without a reference point the terms *"input"* and *"output"* are ambiguous and therefore essentially meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a particularly well formulated question.

A common way to do this is with an FTDI cable or similar USB to UART bridge

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The USB to UART bridge connection is made but I am not entirely sure on how to send data similar to as shown in the simulation image `data_in_sim` directly from my PC and to the board. How can I make either **Python** or maybe **C** script communicate with my hardware design?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).